# Parsing user options into custom data types with OptParse-Applicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

I'm trying to build a CLI food journal app.

And this is the data type I want the user input to be parsed in.

```
data JournalCommand =
  JournalSearch Query DataTypes Ingridents BrandOwnder PageNumber
  | JournalReport Query DataTypes Ingridents BrandOwnder PageNumber ResultNumber
  | JournalDisplay FromDate ToDate ResultNumber
  | JournalStoreSearch Query DataTypes Ingridents BrandOwnder PageNumber ResultNumber StoreFlag
  | JournalStoreCustom CustomEntry OnDate StoreFlag
  | JournalDelete FromDate ToDate ResultNumber
  | JournalEdit CustomEntry ResultNumber
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and because there's a lot of overlap I have a total of 8 functions with `Parser a` type.

Functions like these

```
-- | Search Query
aQueryParser :: Parser String
aQueryParser = strOption
               ( long "search"
                 <> short 's'
                 <> help "Search for a term in the database"
               )
```

The idea if to ultimately have a function like this

```
runJournal :: JournalCommand -> MT SomeError IO ()
runJournal = \case
             JournalSearch q d i b p
                     -> runSearch q d i b p
             JournalReport q d i b p r
                     -> runSearchAndReport q d i b p r
            ...
            ...
```

where `MT` is some monad transformer that can handle `error` + `IO`. Not sure yet.

The question is: How do I setup the `parseArgs` function

```
parseArgs :: IO JournalCommand
parseArgs = execParser ...
```

and `parser` function

```
parser :: Parser JournalCommand
parser = ...
```

so that I'd be able to parse user input into `JournalCommand` and then return the data to relevant functions.

I know I can `fmap` a data type like this

```
data JournalDisplay { jdFromDate     :: UTCTime
                    , jdToDate       :: UTCTime
                    , jdResultNumber :: Maybe Int
                    }
```

as

```
JournalDisplay
<$>
fromDateParser
<*>
toDateParser
<*>
optional resultNumberParser
```

But I'm not sure how to go about doing that with my original data structure.

I think I need to have a list like this `[Mod CommandFields JournalCommand]` which I may be able to pass into `subparser` function by concatenating the `Mod` list. I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In optparse-applicative there's the `Parser` type, but also the [`ParserInfo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Types.html#t:ParserInfo) type which represents a "completed" parser holding extra information like header, footer, description, etc... and which is ready to be run with [`execParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Extra.html#v:execParser). 
 We go from `Parser` to `ParserInfo` by way of the [`info`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#v:info) function which adds the extra information as modifiers.

Now, when writing a parser with subcommands, each subcommand must have its own `ParserInfo` value (implying that it can have its own local help and description).

We pass each of these `ParserInfo` values to the [`command`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html) function (along with the name we want the subcommand to have) and then we combine the `[Mod CommandFields JournalCommand]` list using `mconcat` and pass the result to [`subparser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.13.2.0/docs/Options-Applicative-Builder.html#v:subparser). This will give us the top-level `Parser`. We need to use `info` again to provide the top-level description and get the final `ParserInfo`.

An example that uses a simplified version of your type:

```
data JournalCommand =
    JournalSearch String String
  | JournalReport String
  deriving (Show, Eq)

journalParserInfo :: O.ParserInfo JournalCommand
journalParserInfo = 
    let searchParserInfo :: O.ParserInfo JournalCommand
        searchParserInfo = 
            O.info
            (JournalSearch 
                <$> strArgument (metavar "ARG1" <> help "This is arg 1")
                <*> strArgument (metavar "ARG2" <> help "This is arg 2"))
            (O.fullDesc <> O.progDesc "desc 1")
        reportParserInfo :: O.ParserInfo JournalCommand
        reportParserInfo = 
            O.info
            (JournalReport 
                <$> strArgument (metavar "ARG3" <> help "This is arg 3"))
            (O.fullDesc <> O.progDesc "desc 2")
        toplevel :: O.Parser JournalCommand
        toplevel = O.subparser (mconcat [ 
                command "search" searchParserInfo, 
                command "journal" reportParserInfo 
            ])
     in O.info toplevel (O.fullDesc <> O.progDesc "toplevel desc")
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for a very detailed and easy to understand answer!